# How to "inherit" style to math inline?

Tags: math-mode, italic, inline, boldmath

I've been looking for this a while now, but nobody seems to use the word "inherit", so now I'm asking here:

How do I make inline math letters inherit the inline text style, like this:

In this first example it will write all letter in bold since its a section, after double dot it will be also italic, but math is not.

```
\section{HPVExpansion: \textit{For $H$ for the liquid-gas phase boundary}}
```

Is  there a way to force math to do the same style as the rest of the line?

Comment: As a rule, math does not inherit bold and italic qualities from the surrounding text.  Think about it... bold math is often used to denote vectors or matrices.  A blind inheritance of surrounding text attributes could accidentally change the underlying meaning of the math!  Lest we forget, the math alphabet need not be the same as the text alphabet, and so there are some math alphabets that aren't even available in bold.

Comment: Yes I understand this rule. Is there a way to "force" them to "try"?, right now I'm not gonna bolditalic any greek letter or rare symbols, so I don't see any harm.

Comment: Furthermore,  the side bearings of a character are different in maths, because a math letter can have exponents and indices, the spacing between letters which correspond to different variables is slightly wider than for letters in a word, and so on. A text font requires 7 parameters, whereas a symbol maths font requires 22.